# Why is this function not analytic in said point?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I was going over a proof of Cauchy's integral formula and found the following function

$$
g(w)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}\quad &\text{if } w\neq z,\\[3mm]
f'(z)\quad &\text{if }w=z.
\end{cases}
$$
Where $f$ is analytic in a region $A$.

The book states that $g$ is continuous in $A$ but analytic in $A - \{z\}$; it is clear to me that $g$ is indeed continuous in $A$ but I cannot wrap my head around it not being analytic in the point $z$, any suggestions?

Comment: $g$ *is* analytic at the point $z$, but one has to prove it. The analycity in $A - \{z\}$ is “obvious” because there $g$ is the quotient of two analytic functions with a non-zero denominator. But analycity at the point $z$ is not immediately obvious.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, will get to prove it! A later result states that an analytic function is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, with this, it's clear that $g$ is indeed analytic in $A$, right? However, without such result what would you suggest? Using the definition could be a good starting point.